# Hive: select * is ok but select a column fails

Tags: hive

It is very strange that when I input the Hive query:

```
SELECT * FROM tb LIMIT 1;
```

It returns a row from the table successfully.

However, when I select a column from the table, Hive will fail:

```
SELECT col FROM tb LIMIT 1;
```

Hive gives an error message:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. GC overhead limit
>   exceeded

What is wrong with Hive?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a java memory error. The reason why a select * works, but a select column doesn't, is that the select * just pulls a row of data from HDFS rather than actually executing a map-reduce job.

You might be able to solve the problem by increasing the maximum heap size:

```
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
```

would set the heap size to 512m, for example.

Comment: It turns out that my issue has something to do with the user permission. Hive seems to set a limited heap size for non-owners when he/she submits a query.